# Most effective way to detect if a specific external exe program is currently running using vb.net code?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I need a way for my VB.NET program to detect if certain external programs are running while its running however, I dont want someone to be able to circumvent this by changing the external exe program (im trying to detect) by simply change the program's title bar text or the executable's file name. I'm trying to write this detection code using vb.net. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Please include some sample code if you know how to code it.

Comment: If you don't want to identify them by name or window text, how do you propose that you identify them?  You must have some particular identifying characteristic in mind.  Is there some API or Framework method that you want to detect when its being called or something like that?

Comment: Maybe it could be detect by some objects class name that is unique to the external programs to detect it without relying on the title bar text or exe filename? If this is possible how would I go about doing this?

Comment: You can look at the modules for each process:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.modules  But you need elevated security to do so.

Comment: If you have the source code from the external app then you can tweak it to register a mutex with a specific name (a GUID). Then from your VB.NET app check if a mutex with this name is present -> external app is running.

Comment: Thanks for the idea however I dont wont have access to the external programs. Does anyone know how to check all currently running external exe programs title bar text for a particle string in VB.NET?